# Microsoft Excel IE Automation - Selecting an Item from a Drop Down Checklist

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, automation

I am trying to create an IE automation to select the correct item from a dropdown check list. All items are set to automatically be checked when the site starts up. I am having difficulty getting any of the boxes I don't need to uncheck. Here is the html code

```
<div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;" onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;" style="display:inline-block;border-color:DarkGray;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;overflow:auto;background-color:window;display:none;position:absolute;z-index:11;">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:window;">
                <tr>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap"><span><input id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00" type="checkbox" name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl07$divDropDown$ctl00" checked="checked" onclick="$get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07').control.OnSelectAllClick(this);" /><label for="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00">(Select All)</label></span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap"><span><input id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl02" type="checkbox" name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl07$divDropDown$ctl02" checked="checked" onclick="$get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07').control.OnValidValueClick(this, 'ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00');" /><label for="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl02">Shift&nbsp;1</label></span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap"><span><input id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl03" type="checkbox" name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl07$divDropDown$ctl03" checked="checked" onclick="$get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07').control.OnValidValueClick(this, 'ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00');" /><label for="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl03">Shift&nbsp;2</label></span></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap"><span><input id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl04" type="checkbox" name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl07$divDropDown$ctl04" checked="checked" onclick="$get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07').control.OnValidValueClick(this, 'ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00');" /><label for="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl04">Shift&nbsp;3</label></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table><span><input type="hidden" name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl07$divDropDown$ctl01$HiddenIndices" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl01_HiddenIndices" value="0,1,2" /></span>
        </div><iframe id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl11_ctl01" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;" onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;"
```

Here is what I have tried to do:

```
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ieObj.readyState = 4
    ieObj.document.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl02").Checked = "Unchecked"
```

The box for this element remains unchanged. Any suggestions on how to change this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: ieobject.document.querySelector("#ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl00").click first?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the checked value to `False` to make it unchecked.

The sample code is like this:

```
Sub LOADIE()
    Set ieA = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ieA.Visible = True
    ieA.navigate "http://www.example.com"
    Do Until ieA.readyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop

    ieA.document.getElementById("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_divDropDown_ctl02").Checked = False
End Sub
```

The result is like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the quick response, however when i make this change the boxes still show up as marked. Is it because of the “select all” option that controls the other boxes? I cannot manipulate that box either bc it does not a CHECKED variable.

Comment: It might be. You could try to click the "select all" option first like @QHarr suggested in the comment.